# Change file permissions in DDMS (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, ddms

I'm trying to test the behavior of my application when it cannot access some files due to missing permissions.

Is it possible to change file/folder permissions on an android emulator using FileExplorer in DDMS perspective?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change permissions in the emulator you need to use the `adb shell` command from your adroid-sdk platform-tools. In the android shell you can enter the command `su` to get root access. Now you can see and change the permissions with the normal unix commands `chmod`

**Note**, that the system folder in Android is mounted read-only. You would have to remout it read-write after this tutorial:

http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html

Be careful in anyway to use only writable filesystems like `/data` or `sdcard`for your application data since using restricted folders can have negative side effects in a productive environment!