# how to change permission of DDMS / File Explorer / sdcard?

Tags: android

My sdcard permission is now d---------. How to change the sdcard permission as drwxrwxrwx. I need help. Please give me any one answer. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473573/change-file-permissions-in-ddms-android
This link may have the answer for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commands..

- $ adb shell
- $ su
- $ mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

Try this and let me know what happen..

Answer (score 2):

Go to android sdk Manager and cllck edit button on  your current emulator.check whether you mention the sdcard memory

Answer (score 0):

go to Android virtual Device manager->Edit->Hardware->new->sdcard support

Answer (score 0):

You need  be root to acheive this. If you need it in emulator grab a rooted emulator , you can find one [here](http://www.ehalm.at/avd-2.2-market.php?l=en).Then you can use the **Terminal Emulator** for giving permission or if you don't want to write any command just install the rootexplorer app and use it for giving permission.