# how to create a folder on external sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have pbm in creating a folder on sd card.
this is how i did,

```
adb shell

mkdir /mnt/extSdCard/tmp
mkdir failed for /mnt/extSdCard/tmp, Permission denied
```

which gives me error like above,

any help regarding the same is appreciated.

I have also tried other command like
`mkdir /storage/extSdCard/tmp` which gives me same error.

-Thanks,
Manju

Comment: does extSdCard exist?

Comment: permission denied seems you need write permission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633697/how-to-change-permission-of-ddms-file-explorer-sdcard. might help

Comment: able to create folder/files by program but adb shell commands fails !!

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an external sdcard?

do `ls /mnt/extSdCard`

you cannot create file in extSdCard it needs root permissions.
use /sdcard instead

Comment: external sd card is mounted and very much present on the device, below is the ls command from adb shell to display the contents of sdcard                                                                        $ ls /storage/extSdCard
DevIcon.fil
DevLogo.fil
LOST.DIR
logger

Comment: oops i meant `ls -l`. wanted to check the permissions

Comment: ls -l on external sd card below,                                                     lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2013-06-25 14:22 extSdCard -> /storage/ext
SdCard

Comment: the owner of the file is root. so you cannot be creating a new file in that.

Comment: ok, but the permissions to others are rwxrwxrwx. so, i should be still able to create files/folders in it from adb shell right ?

Comment: Could you check if sdcard is working fine? And are you able to create files from a file manager?

Comment: If it needs root permission how come I can copy on it using Windows Explorer?

Answer (score -1):

Go to show view in eclipse and open "file explorer" , there you will find mnt/sdcard..and create folder under that.

Comment: trying to create folder from eclipse still gives me the same error

Comment: when you open file explorer, can you see mnt folder or not?