# Android emulator -- how to change permission for the sdcard on MAC OS X

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

I have read several answers to this question and it did not help me. THere was something about starting the adb shell, but I cannot do this. I read this article

[how to change permission of DDMS / File Explorer / sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633697/how-to-change-permission-of-ddms-file-explorer-sdcard)

So how do I change permission for sdcard? I work with eclipse and emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473573/change-file-permissions-in-ddms-android

Answer (score -1):

add this permission :  on your manifest file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> this will help u same issue i have faced .It get resolved .put it in u r mansifest file